# "=" added to end of query string parameter which doesn't need a value PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with my code that when the user follows an authentication link it should redirect them using

```
header('Location: '.$url.'/register/verified?done');
```

however it takes them to

> someURL/register/verified?done=

I don't know why it's adding the "=" to the end of the URL but it's breaking the link, if I remove the "=" manually in the URL then it works as expected.

Not really sure what could be causing this.

Comment: It consider done as GET parameter

Comment: it's because the post type should have ha value ?done=some value

Comment: @Opt3 why you need done anyway

Comment: you have to rewrite your url before route check.

Comment: which framework you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

The `=` sign is added elsewhere. The following test does not reproduce the problem:

test.php:

```
<?php
$url = "http://localhost";
header('Location: '.$url.'/register/verified?done');
```

starting a server:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:9000
```

sending request:

```
curl -v http://localhost:9000/test.php
```

the response:

```
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> GET /test.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Host: localhost:9000
< Connection: close
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30
< Location: http://localhost/register/verified?done
< Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The response contains Location header as expected.